# Make the current point of a C# stream the beginning

Tags: c#, stream

I have to read some bytes of a C# stream and then pass the stream to a library method, which should read the rest of it. Unfortunately, this method calls a stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin). Thus, it will read the first bytes, which it cannot understand.

Can I reset the beginning of a stream to its current position? I do not want to copy the whole rest of the stream into a MemoryStream, because it might be quite large.

Comment: No you can't. What you can do is to SAVE current position to RESTORE it later after you called that external method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's nothing that does that... but what you could do is create your own *wrapper* stream which maintains a reference to the original stream, and delegates all calls to it... modifying any `Seek()` or `Position` calls appropriately. You may find that for your purposes, you can make some of the more esoteric calls (such as async support) just throw `NotImplementedException`, for simplicity.

Comment: Is it a decorator pattern?